# how to remove background from image without matching background in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, background

how to remove background from an image without matching background.
For example if i want to remove background from this below image then for removing background sample background image  should not be given. 
[image]

Comment: How do you define backgrounds for general images?

Comment: hi, have you done this task? please answer my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15226784/how-to-remove-background-from-an-image

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think there is no simple answer to this question. In the first place, you should find a method to tell Matlab what the background is. Read about [segmentation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segmentation_%28image_processing%29) (dividing image into coherent parts) .

In general, you will use different approach to different type of images. For example if there is always face on image you can utilize face recognition techniques and support them with some kind of edge detection and so on.